# Defining interface in a function

Tags: typescript

Setting aside how forced this example is, is there a reason to ever define an interface in a function? And are there reasons other than consistency to not allow people to define interfaces in functions (as opposed to at the file-level or as exports in a shared interface/type file)?

```
function Bar() {
  interface Foo {
    x: string;
    y: number;
  }

  return { x: 'bar', y: 2 } as Foo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an anonymous type declaration like this:

```
function Bar(): { x: string; y: number; } {
  return { x: 'bar', y: 2 };
}
```

This is useful if you know what you want to return *before* you write the code to do that, but also do not need to declare anything of "being" that type explicitly. By doing this, any `return` that does not match the type will trigger a compiler error. This is especially helpful when you need to have multiple `return` statements.

If somewhere else you want to refer to that as a "type" you do need to declare it at a top level scope.